# How to prove a transcendental equation is never zero or sometimes zero?

Tags: proof-writing, symbolic-computation, transcendental-functions

I am an engineer by profession. Recently, while working on beams, I obtained the following transcendental equation: $$1-\cos(x)\cosh(x)+x^2\sin(x)\sinh(x)$$. I was wondering if this expression can ever become zero?

I could prove the case that it cannot be identically equal to zero (considering the first two terms together as one term and the $\sin(x)$term as the second term). But I could not prove it for general case.
I tried using asymptotics to see what happens at very large and very small $x$ in hope that it may reveal something, but I am dead lost.
Is there any way or approach to prove such things?

Thanking you in advance!

P.S.: I have graphed the function in MATLAB and MAPLE, but there seems to a numerical issue. The figure shows the graph crossing zero, but substituting that value of $x$ in the function produces non-zero value.

Comment: It does, if $x=0$. So presumably you are interested in $x>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since:

- $f$ is continuous;
- $f\left(\frac\pi2\right)=1+\frac14\pi^2\sinh\left(\frac\pi2\right)>0$;
- $f\left(\frac{3\pi}2\right)=1-\frac94\pi^2\sinh\left(\frac{3\pi}2\right)<0$,

$f$ has a zero in the interval $\left(\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}2\right)$, by the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Thank you for the response! This lead to some other questions, but I intend to tackle them by myself to start.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the last term of the equation, the zero's of function
$$f(x)=1-\cos(x)\cosh(x)+x^2\sin(x)\sinh(x)$$ will be "close" to $n\pi$.

If you want to *approximate* them, expand as a Taylor series $f(x)$ around $x=n \pi$ to some order and use series reversion to obtain for example
$$x_{(n)}=n\pi+\frac {\cosh (\pi  n)-(-1)^n } {n^2\pi ^2 -1} \text{csch}(\pi  n)+$$ $$n\pi\frac {\left((-1)^n \cosh (\pi  n)-1\right)^2 (\pi  n \coth (\pi  n)+2)} {(n^2\pi ^2 -1)^3}\text{csch}^2(\pi  n)+\cdots$$ For the first roots
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 3.236938496 &  3.244010785 \\
 2 & 6.308170276 &  6.308218339 \\
 3 & 9.436006897 &  9.436010404 \\
 4 & 12.57269612 &  12.57269669 \\
 5 & 15.71201387 &  15.71201400 \\
 6 & 18.85236951 &  18.85236955 \\
 7 & 21.99321595 &  21.99321596 \\
 8 & 25.13432416 &  25.13432417 \\
  9 & 28.27558465 &  28.27558465 \\
 10 & 31.41693968 &  31.41693968
\end{array}
\right)$$